# iOS - check if Timer is valid or not

Tags: ios, swift, timer

In my iOS application, I need to do an action whenever there is no result coming in for 2 seconds.

So I set a timer at the beginning:

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.noResults), userInfo: nil, repeats:false)
```

and whenever I get results, I destroy the timer and start a new timer object. I check if timer is valid to know if 2 seconds has been reached. When I get no results for 2 seconds, I do some action:

```
if result != nil {
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.noResults), userInfo: nil, repeats:false)
}

if timer.isValid {
    print("has not been 2 seconds yet")
} else {
    print("do some action")
}
```

This isn't working and I never get to the `do some action` clause. Can someone point me to the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, instead of using `timer.isValid`, how about change to `timer != nil`, like following,

```
if result != nil {
    timer.invalidate()
//        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.noResults), userInfo: nil, repeats:false)
}

if timer != nil { // here
    print("has not been 2 seconds yet")
} else {
    print("do some action")
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I tried this actually, XCode gives the warning `Comparing non-optional value of type 'Timer' to nil always returns false` if I compare timer to `nil`

Comment: how did you declare `timer` ? variable
is it something like `var timer: Timer?`

Comment: It's in the post, I declared it like `var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.noResults), userInfo: nil, repeats:false)`

Comment: So, how about you declare your timer variable in class level (outside viewdidload:) like `var timer: Timer?` and in side `viewdidload` , just assign to timer like `timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.noResults), userInfo: nil, repeats:false)`, can you try that?

Comment: If I do the above, I get XCode error: `Value of optional type 'Timer?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'invalidate' of wrapped base type 'Timer'`. What does this mean?

Comment: ^ On the line `timer.invalidate()`

Comment: add `?` like this `timer?.invalidate()`

Comment: in addition to invalidate timer, i normally add `timer = nil` after `timer?.invalidate()` line

Comment: This makes sense, but for some reason the `do some action` clause is still never reached. Even though I know it's been 2 seconds because I print out `print("No result for 2 seconds")` inside the selector object. Even if I add `timer = nil` after `timer?.invalidate()`

Comment: oh 1 question , why you assign to `timer` variable again after you invalidate?

Comment: So that I can start a new timer counting down to 2 seconds to see if no result has been coming in, and can safely proceed to do some action. The idea is I do not know if result is steadily coming in, so I have to rely on a timer to tell me if no result has come for 2 seconds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186389/discussion-between-rurouni-and-user8571142).